# What happened to Billie "The Blue Bear" after knocking out Maggie in Million Dollar Baby?

Tags: plot-explanation, million-dollar-baby

In the movie [*Million Dollar Baby* (2004)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0405159/), after Billie "The Blue Bear" knocks out Maggie, what would have happened to her and her title? Would she be banned from Boxing?

Comment: This is better suited for a Sports-based website since it doesn't have to do with the plot of Million Dollar Baby.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and answer this for the heck of it...

Boxers sign waivers that indemnify them from any wrongdoing in the ring, *so long as they're acting within the rules*.  In the case of The Blue Bear, the punch was thrown after the bell was rung and while Maggie had her back to her.  This would be considered an illegal punch (possibly a [rabbit punch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbit_punch) but definitely illegal since it came after the bell), and therefore no waiver could protect her from criminal negligence.

As such, she would likely lose her belt as well as face criminal charges.

I took a cursory glance at this Wiki page and didn't see any specific cases where this occurred, all deaths I saw were due to legal blows.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Deaths_due_to_injuries_sustained_in_boxing